# Polynomials and vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $V=K[x]$ (the set of polynomials with coefficients in $K$ and indeterminate $x$) and $f\in V$ a fixed element with positive degree. In $V$ we define the next relation: if $a, b \in V$, we say that $a$ relates to $b$ ($a\sim b$) if and only if $f$ divides $a-b$. We denote as $\bar{a}$ to the equivalence class of $a\in V$, and we denote as $V/ \langle f \rangle $ to the set of equivalence classes.

I have to demonstrate that $V/ \langle f \rangle $  has the structure of a vector space over $K$ if we define the sum and the scalar product as:
$\bar{a}+\bar{b}= \overline{a+b}$, and $\lambda \cdot \bar{a}= \overline{\lambda a}$.
Also, I have to determine the neutral element of $V/ \langle f \rangle $. As well as the dimension of $V/ \langle f \rangle $.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried?

Comment: First task is the prove that these two operations are well defined, then proceed to verify the axioms of vector spaces

Comment: Could be useful the notation $[p]_{\sim}$ for the equivalence class of a polynomial $p \in \mathbb{K}[x]$. Infact if $[p]_{\sim}+[q]_{\sim}=[p+q]_{\sim}$ and $\lambda [p]_{\sim}=[\lambda p]_{\sim}$, it means that the operations on classes are well-defined in $V/ \langle f \rangle$ (because the quotient space inherits the operations of $\mathbb{K}[x]$).